# need an explanation about a strange instruction in jquery.chosen by harvesthq

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

I'm trying to tweak a bit jquery.chosen by harvesthq (
I was lightly editing his plugin when I met this line

```
searchText = this.search_field.val() === this.default_text ? "" : $('<div/>').text($.trim(this.search_field.val())).html();
```

I can't figure what is doing the last part of it specially

```
$('<div/>')
```

makes no sense for me.

I assume it's a way to convert or protect the chars entered in search_field, but didn't find anything like this before.

Can someone explain it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('<div/>')` simply creates a new `<div></div>` element, which harvestq then fills with the search query, leaving you with:

```
<div>Your search Query</div>
```

You can read about jQuery's element creation [in the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2)

Answer (score 4):

```
$('<div/>')
```

creates a new div that is not a part of the document.

```
$('<div/>').text(
  $.trim(this.search_field.val())
).html()
```

Sets the new div's content to the search field value as a text, then reads it as HTML. This effectively HTML-escapes the value. `$.trim` only removes whitespace from the ends of the search string.

Continuing further:

```
this.search_field.val() === this.default_text ? "" : ...
```

will use the empty string if the search field value is the default text, otherwise it uses said HTML-escaped search string.

```
searchText = ...
```

simply assigns that into a variable.